# How to add words into Entry Boxes as recommendation (Tkinter)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to show an Entry Box with already written words in it. (you can think it as a recommendation)

Therefore, if it is correct, users could ignore it (save time). But if it is not correct, users could directly fix it.

Would appreciate any helps. I really dont know what to do so there is no "my code here"

P/s: I am using Python 3, and Tkinter.

Comment: This question can be answered by simply reading the `Entry` widget documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `insert`

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
e = Entry(root)
e.insert(END, 'your_text')
e.pack()
root.mainloop()
```